# How to get Vimeo video id from thumbnail url

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

I was testing Vimeo API and got stuck. I have a Vimeo video thumbnail url and I want to get video id from it. Is it even possible to do that? As far as I looked, thumbnails are generated randomly by frames.

Example: I have a thumbnail ([https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{id}](https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/%7Bid%7D)) and I need to get real video id from it because id in this URL is only for thumbnail / randomly generated by frames.

Comment: Use Regex or JQuery to grab the embeded iframe, and parse the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to my comment, parse the URL using Regex. This is parsing the id from an https URL.

In regards to your updated post, it seem's that Vimeo dynamically updates the thumbnail filename's which makes sense, as there would be a need have more than one for each video. And in this regard, it does not seem to be easily relatable to reverse or conceive a video **ID** from the thumbnail.

Obviously using a similar method below, you would be able to get the ID of a Viemo video, by the actually video permalink. But since you **after editing** your post clarified you are asking to retrieve a video ID from a thumbnail.

> I suggest you sign up for Vimeo's developer API.

You then may retrieve information all at once in a proper fashion.

http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/9696328.xml

**Note**: Or simply do it in reverse, video then retrieve the thumbnail if this is applicable for your situation.

```js
// Comment Suggestion GalaxyCat105: 
// RegX: /(https|http):\/\/(www\.)?i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/(\d+)($|\/)/


function thumbnail(url) 
{       // Match ending, minus extension
        let m = url.match(/(?:[^/][\d\w\.]+).+?(?=_)/);
        url = m[0]
        // Strip URL
        m = url.match(/(https|http):\/\/(www\.)?i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/(\d+)($|\/)/);
        console.log(m[3]);
}

thumbnail('https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/834713810_260x147.jpg');
```

Comment: Sorry for unclear question but what I need is to get video ID, not thumbnail ID. Thumbnail ID is different from video ID. It is quite unusual thing. I want to watch a video but I only have thumbnail picture of that video. I hope I made it clear because it may be a stupid question.

Comment: To make it match both `https` and `http`, use `/(https|http):\/\/(www\.)?i.vimeocdn.com\/video\/(\d+)($|\/)/`

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Thanks, applied.

Comment: @Oxygen Thumbnail's are generated dynamically. This is because video's might be changed, edited, thumbnail preview set, etc. This can not be statically implemented. That seem's why it is a dynamic URL each time for the thumbnail ID. Seems you are attempting something that might not be possible, maybe if it is applicable, go backwards video to thumbnail, a lot easier.

Comment: Heads up, that API on the /api/v2/video path is deprecated: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042975791-Deprecated-APIs-libraries-and-upload-methods

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Looks like it is kinda impossible.

Comment: @Oxygen No problem, will comment if I hear anything in the future to update you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, I've been searching for a solution too.
For me i'm able to get a 50/50 resolving if I just use the {id} in the following url
([https://vimeo.com/video/{id}](https://vimeo.com/video/%7Bid%7D))
Older videos will resolve to a working player others will not.